# Protractor e2e test fails on Saucelabs but it works fine on local selenium grid

Tags: jasmine, protractor, selenium-grid, saucelabs, e2e-testing

We are using Protractor 1.3.1 and most of the teams complaint when they run tests on Saucelabs grid. Because the same set of tests works fine on local grid all the times. Upon debugging what I noticed on the Saucelabs grid is that it sometimes resolves protractor promises fine but sometime it doesn't. For resolution we have to stop relying on protractor promises which makes our jasmine-protractor code ugly and of course extra efforts.

As I described the failures happens after any promise related events like click(), sendKeys(), customWaitFunction(), etc.

I wonder if it's older version of protractor or there is some network latency that is causing those failures? Any suggestion to improve test success rate is highly appreciated.

Notes:
- Almost all the apps are non-angular applications.
- Contacted Saucelabs people and they don't see any issue rendering the app suggesting to resolves the issue in script.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to the latest (currently 2.2.0) protractor?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. The framework we build doesn't work with the latest version and that upgrade is work in progress. I am thinking of trying to run some tests standalone and try with 2.2.0

Comment: @alecxe After some mock setup, I could run the test upgrading protractor to 2.2.0. Strangely, running test locally behave exactly it does on selenium grid with protractor 1.3.1.